# c and java arithmetic expression and parenthesis

Tags: c, math, expression, similarity, arithmetic-expressions

can anyone help me to understand how are translated this 2 expression:

FIRST

```
double val = 1/(b-1)/t*log(x1/x2);
```

I have broke it with some c in many parts, but I have 2 different results:

```
double val2 = ( 1/(b-1) ) / ( t*log(x1/x2) );


double b,t,x1,x2;
b= 0.1;
t= 0.2;
x1 = 0.3;
x2=0.4;

double val = 1/(b-1)/t*log(x1/x2);
printf ("%1.4e",val);

double val2 = ( 1/(b-1) ) / ( t*log(x1/x2) );
printf ("%1.4e",val2);

if(val!=val2){
  printf("different!");
}else printf("its ok");
return 0;
```

SECOND QUESTION:
Are there many differences of precision from double in c and java for very low order numbers?

Thank you.

Comment: `double` (as well as `float`) arithmetic is not precise by their nature.

Comment: The problem might be different evaluation order of the expressions due to different parenthesis. In general, you should never precisely compare two floats, but use ranged compare within an acceptable error.

Comment: Please do some research on your own. Floating point arithmetics is a very complex subject. Small changes might result in great variations. For now, **please** keep in mind never to use floating point if you need exact calculations, like for currencies.

Answer (score 2):

Multiplication and division is done left-to-right, so equal to:

```
((1 / (b - 1)) / t ) * log(x1/x2);
```

This differs from your val2 as the log is 'above the division line'.

Comment: You are basically right about the error, but this is about operator associativity, not evaluation order (there is no sequence point in the expression). Yet the compare might still fail after the correction.

Comment: thank you, can you help me with the second expression?

Comment: sure: x1 = x1 + (h[j]*exp(-lambda[j]*t)); Any more homework you want done :)

Comment: @Olaf: I would like to understand your point. When the operator precendence is equal (like multiplication and division) the operation is done left-to-right as far as I know. Is this what you mean with evaluation order?

Comment: @MichaelD: Olaf is saying that while the result must be the same _as-if_ done left-to-right, the compiler and CPU may decide to do operations in a different order, e.g. `log(x1/x2)` may be executed before, or concurrently with `((1 / b - 1)) / t )`.

Comment: @ninjalj: Almost;-) There is no specific evaluation order for the operations, as long as the result would be _mathematically_ correct. Problem ist, computer floating point does not behave mathematically correct (limited number of bits), so the evaluation order might generate small variations of the result. Associativity is left-to-right, but that is just how the operands are selected (that's why you have to use parenthesis here). Briefly: floating point arithmetic is a tar-pit; that's why you should avoid it where possible and reasonable and always if you need full precision (e.g. currency)..

Comment: Associativity (left-to-right) and priority are different from execution sequence. For instance: `a*b + c*d` has all left-assiciativity, but the two multiplications can be performed in any order. This might generate slight variations of the result due to rounding errors.